# Haskell threaded mode switch in pragma

Tags: multithreading, haskell, network-programming

All the searching through pragma documentation I couldn't find a way to flip threaded on/off with pragmas, any tips? Don't want to create a cabal file just for this little code I'm playing with, but I think changing the threaded mode will make my killThread attempt be able to kill a thread that was forked with this, also let me know if even the threaded switch won't let me kill this thread (running in windows):

```
repeatAccept s p = do
  c <- accept s
  t <- forkFinally (echoHandler c) (exitPool p)
  atomically $ do
    p' <- readTVar p
    writeTVar p ((t,c):p')
  repeatAccept s p
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`-threaded` is a static flag](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html#id612286), so you can't set it using [`{-# OPTIONS_GHC #-}`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/ch04s02.html#source-file-options).

You're out of luck. Bite the bullet and write a .cabal file.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still too lazy so just ghc -threaded from the command line, good 'nuff for fiddling heh

Comment: At least write a shell script so you only have to type `build` each time.